# Como funciona o auto increment com chaves compostas no engine MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, auto-incremento, chave-primária

Acabei pegando uma tabela para manipular, notei que algumas vezes o valor do auto increment se repetia, a primeira coisa que me chamou a 
atenção foi que a primary key era composta de dois campos um deles era AI e o outro não.

Montei um exemplo que reproduz esse comportamento:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   c2 varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   c3 varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (c2, id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Inserts

```
INSERT INTO t(c2, c3) VALUES ('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('A', 'C')
```

Resultado do select:

```
# |id|c2|c3
1 |1 |A |A
2 |1 |B |A
3 |1 |C |A
4 |2 |A |B
5 |2 |B |C
6 |2 |C |B
7 |3 |A |C
```

Qual é a lógica do auto increment quando ele faz parte de uma chave primária composta?

Answer (score 5):

### Solução (se realmente precisar de um PK composta com campo AI)

O 'problema' é restrito ao engine MyISAM, pois o InnoDB não permite esse tipo de construção.
Essa repetição acontece apenas quando o campo auto increment não é o primeiro da da primary key composta `PRIMARY KEY (c2, id)`. Ao inveter a ordem dos campos
o auto increment funciona de forma sequencial como esperado.

```
DROP TABLE t;

CREATE TABLE t (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  c2 varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  c3 varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, c2)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO t(c2, c3) VALUES ('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('A', 'C');

SELECT * FROM t
```

Resultado do select:

```
# |id|c2|c3
1 |1 |A |A
2 |2 |A |B
3 |3 |B |A
4 |4 |B |C
5 |5 |C |A
6 |6 |C |B
7 |7 |A |C
```

### Como funciona

Antes do valor do auto increment ser determinado é feita um checagem do valor da outra(s) coluna(s)(PK), caso ele exista (ver inserts 1, 2 e 7) 
a coluna AI terá seu valor incrementado em +1 do contrário seu valor será 1, ou seja incremento funciona pelo 'grupo'.

Comment: Quando você diz "o InnoDB não permite esse tipo de construção" você se refere a chave composta com uma das colunas AI?

Comment: @PedroTeles exato, é retornado o erro: `Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`