# ID auto incremento em relação a outro campo

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, auto-incremento, chave-primária, chave-composta

Há um tempo estou a procura de algo para resolver tal problema que venho encontrando em outros sistemas que desenvolvi, gostaria de saber uma solução para como fazer um id auto incremento, porém um auto incremento relacionado a outro campo, por exemplo: Tenho minha tabela de produtos e esses produtos são categorizados, assim eles possuem um `id_categoria`, que referência a tabela de categorias e meu `id` da tabela de produtos é `auto increment`, e tenho uns registros na tabela de produtos que seriam assim por exemplo:

```
id | id_categoria
 1 | 1
 2 | 3
 3 | 2
 4 | 1
 5 | 2
 6 | 1
 7 | 4
 ...
```

Mas gostaria que esse auto incremente só acontecesse com relação a categoria, por exemplo para a categoria de id_categoria eu tenho o produto de id 1,2,3,4,5, *sabendo que eu teria de ter uma chave primária composta, tendo o id do produto e o id da categoria como chaves primárias*, minha tabela ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
id | id_categoria
 1 | 1
 1 | 2
 1 | 3
 1 | 4
 2 | 1
 2 | 2
 3 | 1
 ...
```

*Mas sem eu precisar de primeiro consultar o banco e depois adicionar o id desejado, algo que fosse automático feito pelo banco, alguém conhece alguma solução para isso?*

Comment: Mesmo que houvesse - não sei se há -, o banco estaria fazendo exatamente isso "consultando a base para ver qual numero gerar". Por que você não cria uma função para fazer isso? Dessa maneira você pode coloca-la em seus inserts ou updates e irá parecer que é uma função nativa do banco.

Comment: Chegou a ver [Como funciona o auto increment com chaves compostas no engine MyISAM?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113958/91) ? é isso que vc deseja?

Comment: @reginaldo-rigo dessa forma ok, posso fazer uma trigger, ja usei dessa forma, mas gostaria de saber se possui algo já nativo do banco que auxilie nisso.

Comment: @rray isso não, pois ali está passando o id do produto já na consulta, para isso deveria realizar uma consulta antes e como dito na pergunta não quero realizar isso.

Comment: O resultado que você deseja na segunda ilustração seria na tabela de produtos, na tabela de categorias ou em uma terceira tabela do relacionamento entre as duas?

Comment: Na tabela de produtos...

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, você está criando um relacionamento N:N, ou seja, 1 produto pode ter N categorias, e uma determinada categoria pode estar vinculada a N produtos, neste caso o melhor modelo é a criação de 3 tabelas, tbl_produto, tbl_categoria, tbl_produto_categoria com os campos id_produto e id_categoria sendo ambos uma chave composta, pensando neste modelo os produtos estarão cadastrados e as categorias também, o que você precisa é vincular um ao outro, então não faz muito sentido o que você deseja fazer no meu ponto de vista, entendo que você estão fugindo totalmente do padrão.