# Protocolo para documentos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou fazendo um programa em php, mysql e gostaria de gerar um protocolo com alguns argumento.

O protocolo seria gerado automaticamente no sistema, sem interferência do usuário, porém ele teria que ser os seguintes padrões:

**Numeração:** 
A cada novo cadastro ele teria que incrementar o valor e não repetir, seguindo a lógica a seguir:

```
0001/ano --> 0001/2017
0002/ano --> 0002/2017
```

Outro ano teria que virar pro 0001 novamente:

```
0001/ano --> 0001/2018
0002/ano --> 0002/2018
```

***Como poderia implementar isso no sistema?***

Estava pensando em pegar o ano atual da última parte do protocolo, exemplo 2017, e se não retornar nenhuma linha ele iniciaria o contador do protocolo partindo do 0001, assim que fosse gravado o 2017 o contador já teria uma linha e ele continuaria a sequencia lógica, porém como vou pegar o próximo número?

Comment: Está usando o MySQL como banco?

Comment: Isso mesmo, php, mysql, html5, JS

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua lógica, porém para implementar sem ter que ficar o tempo todo retornando o ano atual, ou percorrendo a tabela para saber o índice do protocolo, vc pode criar uma tabela no banco e armazenar o ano atual e o índice atual do protocolo. Cria uma trigger que sempre que for gerado um novo protocolo atualiza o índice e uma função no banco que ao dar 00:00 verifique o ano, e caso seja diferente do atual armazenado no banco então substitua o ano e zere o índice.

Comment: É possível fazer isso com o banco (depende de algumas coisas) ou na aplicação. Logo respondo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Abordagem com MyISAM**

Pré requisitos:

- Ter um chave primária composta.
- O engine da tabela deve ser MyISAM.

**Desvantagens:**

- Se a tabela possuir alguma chave estrangeira a integridade referencial deve ser implementada via aplicação.
- Pode adicionar um pouco de complexidade em updates,deletes e consultas, pois o campo auto increment não será o suficiente para identificar a linha. Ex: um update baseado somente no `id` vai atualizar todos os registros com valor 30 por exemplo de todos os anos (2015, 2016, 2017 etc.)

Uma solução interessante que resolve esse problema só com o banco de dados é criar uma chave composta com auto increment. Um detalhe **importante** na outra de criar a tabela o campo do auto incremente deve ser o **último**. Dessa maneira o número só incrementa baseado no valor da coluna anterior (ano no caso) para cada registro inserido como o valor igual (2017) o auto increment sobe, ao virar o ano (2018) o próximo valor do auto increment será 1.

Exemplo da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `atendimentos` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `ano` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `atendente` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ano`,`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COMMENT='Perceba bem a ordem dos campos da chave primária.'
```

Inserts:

```
INSERT INTO atendimentos (ano, atendente) VALUES(2017, 'Fulano'); //id: 1
INSERT INTO atendimentos (ano, atendente) VALUES(2017, 'Ciclano'); //id: 2
INSERT INTO atendimentos (ano, atendente) VALUES(2017, 'Beltrano'); //id: 3
INSERT INTO atendimentos (ano, atendente) VALUES(2018, 'Novo'); //id: 1
INSERT INTO atendimentos (ano, atendente) VALUES(2019, 'Beltrano'); //id: 1
```

**Relacionda:**

[Como funciona o auto increment com chaves compostas no engine MyISAM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113958/91)

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra abordagem usando apenas o banco de dados, seria procurar o maior valor de protocolo dentro do ano corrente e somar mais um. Segue um exemplo:

```
INSERT tabela
    (
        protocolo,
        ...campos...
    )
VALUES
    (
        (
            SELECT
                CONCAT(MAX(CONVERT(REPLACE('0001/2017', CONCAT('/', CONVERT(YEAR(NOW()), CHAR(4))), ''), UNSIGNED)) + 1, '/' + CONVERT(YEAR(NOW()), CHAR(4)))
            FROM
                tabela AS x
            WHERE
                YEAR(x.data) = YEAR(NOW())
        ),
        ...campos...
    );
```