# Zerar o AUTO_INCREMENT sem perder os dados

Tags: mysql

Estou trabalhando com uma tabela de ofícios, onde o número do ofício e o ano em que ele foi criado são uma chave primária composta. Estou gerando o número do ofício através de *AUTO_INCREMENT* e pegando o ano atual com *php*, porém, gostaria de que por exemplo, quando o ano 2017 chegasse ao fim, o número do ofício voltasse ao início novamente. Pois o ofício 01 do ano 2018 é diferente do ofício 01 do ano 2017.
Minha tabela é essa:

```
CREATE TABLE oficio (
    numero int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ano int,
    interessado varchar(100),
    assunto  text,
    CONSTRAINT pk_NumeroAno PRIMARY KEY(numero,ano)
);
```

Já li sobre o comando:

```
ALTER TABLE oficio AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Mas pra ele funcionar preciso deletar todas as informações do tabela. Como posso zerar o *AUTO_INCREMENTE* sem perder os dados?

Comment: Veja se serve para o seu caso: [Protocolo para documentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/230316/91)

Comment: Lucas eu fiz um teste aqui utilizando "ALTER TABLE oficio AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;" e não zerou minha tabela, ela continuou com os dados.

Comment: Então Kayo, a tabela não é zerada, mas o _AUTO_INCREMENT_ continua no número de antes, entende? Eu precisava que ele voltasse para o primeiro.

Comment: rray, era isso mesmo que eu estava pensando. Vou tentar implementar.

Comment: @LucasRamos  ta quase lá, pelo que vi a a diferença está na ordem dos campos na `primary key`

Comment: Eu só não entendi muito bem a parte do: _ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8_.

Comment: Cada `engine` têm funcionalidades diferentes, por exemplo o `MyISAM` não tem integridade referencial já o `innoDB` tem usa-se cada um para um determinado contexto. o `charset` diz em qual a codificação os dados serão armazenados, no caso é utf-8 mas poderia ser latin-1 ou outro.

Comment: Entendi, e funcionou. Obrigado!